# Как сохранять вошедшего игрока?

Tags: java, cookie, jsoup

Есть игра http://nebo.mobi После входа не нужно заново вводить ник и пароль, так как браузер хранит их в памяти и каким-то образом игра его берет. Так вот, а как мне быть с приложением? После отправки данных для входа (Jsoup, POST) сервер отдает html главной страницы `/home`. Но далее, если я перейду, например, на страницу, доступную лишь вошедшему игроку что произойдет? Ведь надо что-то еще отправлять, верно?

Случайно не куки? Тогда где их взять?

Comment: _доступную лишь вошедшему игроку что произойдет?_ - 403 Forbidden или 401 Unauthorized по идее
_Случайно не куки_ - они самые

Comment: @AGS17, я даже не знаю в этом ничего, а как-то откуда-то в памяти всплыло про куки)

Comment: @AGS17, смотрите - у меня при каждом запуске будет осуществляться вход (юзер об этом не знает) получаю куки и куда его? Как их передавать разобрался но где хранить во время использования программы?

Comment: Что значит хранить? Они хранятся в браузере и при запросе передаются на сервер. Вам не нужно сохранять никакие файлы и тд, если вы об этом

Comment: @AGS17, но у меня не браузер а приложение.. Кажется я что-то не понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но далее, если я перейду, например, на страницу, доступную лишь
>   вошедшему игроку что произойдет? Ведь надо что-то еще отправлять,
>   верно?

Визуальных ссылок (ссылающихся на страницы, к которым нет доступа) по идее быть вообще не должно. Если ссылаться напрямую - то должна возвращаться страница со статус кодами `403 Forbidden` или `401 Unauthorized`. Лично я бы вернул неавторизированному пользователю `401`, а авторизированному, но не имеющего соответствующего уровня доступа `403` ошибки.

> Случайно не куки? Тогда где их взять?

Именно они. Почитать на [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie) что это.

Задаваться они могут как на сервере, так и на клиенте. При каждом запросе они швыряются между клиентом-сервером.

Хороший инструмент для просмотра кук (либо сессионного/локального хранилища) - хромовские `Dev tools` (`F12` кнопка)

Ползем в `Application` > `Cookies` > домен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну допустим я получил куки после авторизации, да? И при всех следующих игровых запросах их надо отправлять, верно? Между входом и какими-то действиями в игре будет разделение на активности (андроид приложение) - значит надо хранить куки.....